# Unable to start debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Similar to [Debugging ASP.NET with IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928957/debugging-asp-net-with-iis) but for different version of visual studio, different OS and his fix didn't work.

Before I shut down my computer last night everything worked fine.  This morning I rebooted and I started getting the error message below when I tried to start debugging my web application:

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img710/3306/errorhd.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img710/3306/errorhd.png)

When I start it without debugging it get a HTTP 503 error.

What would cause this to suddenly break?  How do I fix it?

Comment: The only issue with that message box is MS is notorious for very bad help.  Clicking the help button is the ultimate no no.  You may not get the office paper clip help, but you get some random stupid site about a generic error.  When will help actually help ?

Comment: That's funny because I was thinking the EXACT same thing this morning.  MS help is absolutely worthless....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that this was caused because I recently changed my password.  To fix I had to:

1. Go into IIS
2. click on Application Pools
3. Right click on my DefaultAppPool and
   select Advanced Settings
4. Update the password used for my
   Identity.

Hope this is useful to someone else.